# Django : Get queryset with filters over list (filled and/or empty)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-q

I'm working on a module which let to display objects thanks to filters defined by users.

**View.py file :**

```
search_category = Document.objects.values_list('publication__category__name', flat=True).distinct()
kwargs['search_category'] = search_category

search_format = Document.objects.values_list('format', flat=True).distinct()
kwargs['search_format'] = search_format

search_language = Document.objects.values_list('language', flat=True).distinct()
kwargs['search_language'] = search_language

checkbox_category = self.request.GET.getlist('CategoryChoice')
checkbox_format = self.request.GET.getlist('FormatChoice')
checkbox_language = self.request.GET.getlist('LanguageChoice')
choice_title = self.request.GET.get('TitleChoice')

test_research = Document.objects\
            .filter(Q(publication__category__name__isnull=True) | Q(publication__category__name__in=checkbox_category))\
            .filter(Q(format__isnull=True) | Q(format__in=checkbox_format))\
            .filter(Q(language__isnull=True) | Q(language__in=checkbox_language))\
            .filter(Q(title__isnull=True) | Q(title__in=choice_title))
```

**My template file for one filter (language) :**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-choice" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#language"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="language"><span
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> {% trans 'Language' %}</button>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="language">
              <div class="card card-body card-choice">
                {% for language in search_language %}
                  <input type="checkbox" class="fakeRadio" name="LanguageChoice" value="{{ language }}">
                  {{ language }}<br>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

It looks like this in my web application :

[image]

I can check one or multiple checkboxes, but also none checkbox for a specific criteria. This last option makes issue, because, for example, if I don't check `language`, the resulting queryset is empty and shouldn't be because it should take account the others filters.

**Example :**

```
Object 1 : Category = 'FOOD_CONTACT', Format = 'pdf', Language = 'FR', Title = 'This is my first title'
Object 2 : Category = 'FOOD_CONTACT', Format = 'epub', Language = 'EN', Title = 'This is my second title'
Object 3 : Category = 'OTHER', Format = 'pdf', Language = 'FR', Title = 'ZZ'
```

Now, if I check this :

```
Category filter : ['FOOD CONTACT']
Format filter : []
Language filter : []
Title filter : 
It should return : Object 1, Object 2

Category filter : ['FOOD CONTACT']
Format filter : ['pdf']
Language filter : []
Title filter : 
It should return : Object 1

Category filter : []
Format filter : ['pdf']
Language filter : []
Title filter : 'Z'
It should return : Object 3
```

Comment: Have you tested each of those individual filters from a terminal?

Comment: Did you said for example, just `category` ? Yes I tried each one (just category, just format, ...) and always an empty queryset

Comment: So a query such as `Document.objects.filter(language__in=['EN'])` returns an empty result?

Comment: No it returns something. `Document.objects.filter(language__in=['EN']).filter(format__in=['pdf'])` returns something, but `Document.objects.filter(language__in=['EN']).filter(format__in=[ ])` returns nothing and I would like to get in this case all objects with the first filter.

Comment: It exactly the same process than workshop. You can buy something with filters and it displays objects according to specific filters

Comment: I don't understand the intent of `.filter(format__in=[ ])`.  What is that supposed to do?

Comment: It's maybe a mistake to myself, it just means one language is checked, but none format. I edited my question with a good example from what I would like to do ;)

Comment: Is the title field intended to be an exact match or a partial match?  If the latter, I think you want to use `title__contains` instead of `title__in`.

Comment: Yes it's icontains. But with this modification it doesn't work yet :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to build your filters dynamically, and just don't include any filters that the user didn't ask for.

```
# default to all documents
test_research = Document.objects.all()

# if user entered any search criteria, add those filters
if category:
    test_research = test_research.filter(publication__category__name__in=category)

if format:
    test_research = test_research.filter(format__in=format)

if language:
    test_research = test_research.filter(language__in=language)

if title:
    test_research = test_research.filter(title__icontains=title)
```

Comment: I will try tomorrow at the office ! Are you sure it will combine querysets?

Comment: Yes, it will combine all those filters into one queryset.

Comment: It seems to work fine ! I believed it was possible in one queryset.

Comment: @Essex - I need a clarification; is the query being called within the (Django) `Listview`? If yes, what are the variables e.g. **category**, **format** etc being referred to? I am using two boolean fields in my model and want to apply _filter/s_ at runtime. Currently I am simply using `myModel.objects.filter(<boolean_field1>=False)` etc. I am trying to build in two **checkbox**es in the _ListView_ page which on checking _True_ will apply the required filter. Thanks.